# Show Menu on Google's Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to embed a custom Google Map on my website.
In its upper left corner it has a menu button, which makes the menu appear:

[image]

Is there any way to make the menu visible per default, so that the user doesn't have to click the button?

For embedding the map this code is required:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=14XCls7BAgkChi1bU-9wi4ginYK0" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qs8c18n/).

Comment: Where is the code that triggers the click functionality of the slide menu? If it's just embedded, there's no way you can manipulate the code unless you coded the map yourself.

Comment: @noogui: As you can see, this is just an iframe. I was hoping, there is something like a parameter (e.g. `?menu=visible;`) I can set.